# General Topology and Basis?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a topology $\tau$ has finite basis $B$. Now by second definition of basis there $\exists B_3$ such that of if x $\in B_1\cap B_2$, then x $\in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Now again I choose the set $B_2$ and $B_3$ and by above logic $\exists B_4 \subset B_2 \cap B_3$. And I repeat this process. My claim is there should $\exists$ elements $B_i, B_j, B_k$ such that $B_i = B_j \cap B_k$. For some reason I am finding this statement to be a strong one and hence suspect the my reasoning. So I would like to know if its indeed true or there lies a flaw in my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, $B_1$ and $B_2$ contains $x$, yes, there must be a basis element $B_3$ with $B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$ and $x$ in $B_3$. Likewise  we can find a basis element $B_4 \subseteq B_2 \cap B_3$. etc.

But your basis is finite. So you can't keep on getting new basis elements indefinitely. Therefore you must eventually get  $B_{i}=B_{i+1}=B_{i+2}=\cdots$.

Comment: the statement  "if $B_2 and B_2"$ are not disjoint, I don't understand why should there be a conditional " if ", because it the previous line we have established that x $\in B_1. B_2 ,B_3$ hence they should NOT be disjoint. Also could explain me your last line i.e $B_{i+1}$ = $B_i$ and not $B_i = B_{i-1} \land B_{i-2}$. I certainly couldn't those two statements equivalent.

Comment: True. That's very silly of me. :)